# Why not adding an editor in StackExchange Android app

Tags: discussion

I have tested the StackExchange android app ( available in google play : [StackExchange](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin&hl=fr) ) but unfortunately it doesn't provide an editor which makes writing well formatted questions and answers so hard. I suggest to add an editor for this app.

Comment: How often do you find yourself writing software on your phone? The issue is more the expectation than the implementation.

Comment: Just to let the poster know (in case he didn't) that being downvoted on SO meta means the suggestion is disagreed and not that it's a bad question.

Answer (score 7):

It *has* an editor.  It's probably not as full-featured as the main site's editor, but it more than suffices.

The key to writing anything on the mobile app is to be patient, proofread, and be sure that you're not getting autocorrect errors.

I'd argue that longer questions and answers aren't a good idea on the mobile device, but things that can be explained without a lot of formatting or code work well here.

By the way:  this was written with the mobile app.

Comment: Show us an answer with a code block that was written with the mobile app, and then we'll talk ;)

Comment: I've written one or two with small code snippets before.  Any more than that would mandate a computer (for ease of typing).